# How to store JWT token after login and pass the token in header to authenticate through middle ware to other routes?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

In the controller, after user login successfully, the jwt signs a token, I want to redirect or access other protected Routes. How can I store and then pass this signed token as json header to access other protected Routes?
Can't figure out how to move on from the res.render part in controller.
I've tried in Postman, inserting the token into the Headers and its working, but how do I do this in the NodeJs codes?

authentication middleware check-auth.js:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
        console.log("This is token:" + token);
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_KEY);
        console.log(decoded);
        req.userData = decoded;
        next();
    } catch(error){
        return res.render("LoginFail",{
            viewTitle: "Not Authorized"
        })
    }
};
```

pcl.js (display data) Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const checkAuth = require('../middleware/check-auth');
const PCLController = require('../controller/PCLControllerV2.js')


//Get all pcl data in the database
router.get("/alldata",checkAuth, PCLController.pcl_get_all);

router.get("/recenttop10",checkAuth, PCLController.pcl_get_10);

router.get("/homepage",checkAuth, PCLController.homepage);


module.exports = router;
```

Part of loginController.js

```
exports.loginaction = async function(req, res){

    var sql = "SELECT `Password` FROM usersv2 WHERE Email='"+req.body.email+"'";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql,(err,rows,fields)=>{
        console.log(err);
        if(rows.length > 0){
            if(rows){
                console.log(rows)
                bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, rows[0].Password,(err, result) =>{
                    if(result){
                        //JWT Token
                        const token = jwt.sign(
                            {
                            email: req.body.email,
                            }, 
                            process.env.JWT_KEY,
                            {
                            expiresIn: "1h"
                            }
                        );
                        //console.log(token);
                        
                        return res.render("LoginSuccess",{
                            viewTitle: "Login Success, Redirecting to homepage in 2 seconds..."
                           
                        });
                    }else{
                        return res.render("LoginFail",{
                            viewTitle: "Login Failed, Wrong Password, Redirecting to login page in 2 seconds..."
                        });
                    }
                }); //bcrypt end
            }
        }else{
            res.render("LoginFail",{
                viewTitle: "Login Failed, Email not found, Redirecting to login page in 2 seconds..."
            });
        }    
    }) //mysql end
};
```

Comment: You are facing issue in frontend part, right?

Comment: I am not quite sure, but I think the backend needs to do something (Authenticate the token) so that it can proceed to render the frontend...? Currently looking into Passport, not sure its a better way to achieve what I want.

Comment: For backend, you have to write a middleware which authenticates your incoming requests. For frontend, you can store it in a cookie(if you are using ssr) or local storage.

Comment: If your logic is working using postman then it's fine. JWTs are stateless and you don't have to store them anywhere in your backend. What frontend are you using?

Comment: I am using handlebars to render my webpages